# How to browse using Name column in SSAS cube, when Name column is different from Key column

Tags: ssas, cube

I have a table where a user has multiple contacts. Now, since the contacts can be duplicate, the key column for contacts is changed to unique key in table. 
The cube processed successfully. However, when browsed using contacts attribute, it is considering same contact as different ones as the key column is different for both entries. 
Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can query for the key by using MEMBER_KEY or Key0 per the dimension member properties. For more information, please refer to [Intrinsic Member Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145528.aspx).